# Sklearn MLP Classifier Hidden Layers Optimization (RandomizedSearchCV)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I have the following parameters set up :

```
parameter_space = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': [(sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),), (sp_randint.rvs(100,600,1),)],
    'activation': ['tanh', 'relu', 'logistic'],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'alpha': stats.uniform(0.0001, 0.9),
    'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive']}
```

All the parameters except the hidden_layer_sizes is working as expected.

Currently, the hidden_layer_sizes `random` values are precomputed and remain the same across all iterations.

Is there a way to get 1 or 2 layer MLP with hidden layer neurons between 100 and 600 picked randomly for each iteration of `RandomizedSearchCV`.

Any ideas / other related tips?

Comment: may you specify more what structure is the 'hidden_layer_sizes' is it a tuple of 3 integers or just one number?

Answer (score 0):

The [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) uses [ParameterSampler](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L193) that expects to have a list which is randomly sampled or an object with [attribute](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L262) `rvs()`. You can imitate this object by

```
class RandIntMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high, shape=(1)):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.shape = shape

    def rvs(self, random_state=None):
        np.random.seed(random_state)
        return np.random.randint(self.low, self.high, self.shape)

print (RandIntMatrix(100, 600, 3).rvs())  # [ 506 124 310]
```