# GridSearchCV hidden_layer_sizes Parameter array should be one-dimensional

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Parameter hidden layer sizes like this works:

```
parameters = {
   'hidden_layer_sizes': [[1,2], [3,4]],
}
```

But not like this:

```
parameters = {
   'hidden_layer_sizes': RandIntMatrix(1, 50, (2, 2)).rvs(),
}
```

This line:

```
RandIntMatrix(1, 50, (2, 2)).rvs()
```

Produces random array like this:

```
[[32 33]
 [17 28]]
```

I see there are not commas but I guess that should not be problem.

Here is the file with the error btw:
(Parameter array should be one-dimensional.)

https://necromuralist.github.io/boston_housing/_modules/sklearn/grid_search.html

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032019/sklearn-mlp-classifier-hidden-layers-optimization-randomizedsearchcv

class RandIntMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high, shape=(1)):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.shape = shape

    def rvs(self, random_state=None):
        np.random.seed(random_state)
        return np.random.randint(self.low, self.high, self.shape)
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of `GridSearchCV`, `param_grid` should be a 'Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and _lists_ of parameter settings to try as values, or a list of such dictionaries'. On the other side, what is referenced refers to `RandomizedSearchCV` for which you'll find a different specification for parameter `param_distributions` within the documentation.

Comment: @amiola you are right, RandIntMatrix(1, 50, (2, 2)).rvs().tolist() helped, thanks